# When should I pack an image into the file?

Tags: texturing

When would I not want to use the tab "pack an image as embedded data into the .blend file" ? If I do use it should it only be at the end before final export?

Answer (score 1):

Packing images has nothing to do with exporting. Most exporters have their own ways to deal with textures.

Blender's packing feature allows you to include external resources in your .blend file. This comes in handy when you want to distribute them to other people or showcase them on Sketchfab.

Comment: So are you saying that  even though the image may be being used by a mesh in a scene as a texture, the image itself (i.e. a jpeg) it  "isnt" included in the scene on the mesh in a .blend file unless I pack the jpeg image. So If I close and reopen a .blend file later without packing the image, the image  wont be in the file, or on the mesh?.

Comment: That's correct. If you add a texture to a model, Blender creates a link to said texture. This texture might be in the same folder as the blend file but it also can be somewhere else, like a network location. You can also put everything in the same location and create a zip file, but I think for distributing blend files, the blender-internal pack function is quite handy, because you don't have to worry about the paths to the texture's locations.