# Only half of the object is getting texture, the other half is dark

Tags: texturing

I have a cube and I want to apply a concrete texture to the inside of it but, when i do, it only applies the texture to half of it on the inside and then the other half on the outside of the cube. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't make your questions depend exclusively on others downloading the file, or reading links just to understanding the issue. Please use the [edit] option at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Incorrect, corrected after the first image**

The issue is with your material's bump node. Change it to a *Normal Map* and everything works fine.

I don't know why the *Bump* node doesn't like hollow shapes, but every replica mesh I created and plugged into the material always ended up with those black surfaces. When I unplugged that *Bump* node, the problem went away.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEbZp.png]

**Edit:**

Seems like I finally found the source at the same time as HelloHiHola. You probably meant to plug in your normal image into the *Strength* input, not the *Normal* input.

[image]

Comment: PS: For future reference, you may want to pack all external files into your .blend since people who download it won't have the texture files when you don't do so.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60495/when-should-i-pack-an-image-into-the-file

Comment: @stphnl329 Thanks You! I'll try but I don't know how to do that. Also, thank you so much for the help. That worked for me, but I voted the first helpful comment as answered and I definately would've voted you up if I could do two. Thanks!

Comment: @ProEffectsMAX The first part of this answer is actually the correct way to do it. The edit and the answer you put as solution is actually giving you incorrect results for the texture. A normal map is not supposed to be plugged into the Bump node. Not even into the Normal input of that node without using a Normal Map node.

Comment: @MrTheRich Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Your normal are most likely pointing the wrong way, in edit mode select all faces and press SHIFT+N to normalize their direction.

Comment: That doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Faces have two sides by default so they are always unwrapped on both sides of the face. The darkness (not black as yo u can see a texture there ) you see is a problem with the lighting on the normals.

Make sure when unwrapping you are using the smart UV project instead of the regular unwrap, because i'm seeing some stretching in your unwrapping. (or give your mesh seams where you want the unwrap to "split".)

Comment: That doesn't work here.